# Make a field required if other field contains a specific value with Joi

Tags: joi

How can I refactor with Joi instead of Yup

```
 my_field: Yup.string().when('categories', (categories, field) => (
      categories.map((c: {label: string, value: string}) => c.value).includes('string') ? field.required('My Field is required') : field))
```